# Have a script that changes div after time interval need to alter so it only runs once

Tags: javascript

I have the following `js` that changes `div` content at a `time interval`, I love how it works but need to alter it so `script` only runs once how do I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initChangeText()
{
    var time = 10;
    setInterval('changeText();',time*1000);
}
function changeText()
{
    var divs_ = document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    for (var i = 0;i<divs_.length;i++)
        if (divs_[i].className == "change")
            changeULText(divs_[i]);

}
function changeULText(obj)
{
    var ul = obj.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    var li = obj.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i=0;i<li.length;i++)
    {
        if (li[i].className == "show")
        {
            li[i].className = "";
            li[(i+1)%li.length].className = "show";
            return ;
        }
    }
}
window.onload = initChangeText;
</script>
```

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setTimeout instead of setInterval

```
function initChangeText(){
    var time = 10;
    setTimeout(changeText,time*1000);
}
function changeText(){
    var divs_ = document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    for (var i = 0;i<divs_.length;i++)
        if (divs_[i].className == "change")
            changeULText(divs_[i]);

    }
function changeULText(obj) {
    var ul = obj.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    var li = obj.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i=0;i<li.length;i++){
        if (li[i].className == "show"){
            li[i].className = "";
            li[(i+1)%li.length].className = "show";
            return ;
        }
    }
}
window.onload = initChangeText;
</script>
```